# Is there a better way to write this R if statement

Tags: r

I have a piece of code that creates an SQL query from the columns of a dataframe row:

```
a <- c("a1")
b <- c("b1")
c <- c("c1")
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)

query = "INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES ("

for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
  if (j < ncol(df)) {
    query <- paste0(query, df[1, j], ", ")  
  } else {
    query <- paste0(query, df[1, j], ");")
  }
}
```

The point is I have to insert a comma between the elements, but no comma after the last element so that the query works.

Here is what I want to get:

```
query = "INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES ("a1", "b1", "c1");"
```

Do you have an idea of a simpler way to write it?

Comment: You can use the `collapse` argument to `paste` to put punctuation between items, e.g. `paste0(df[i, ], collapse = ", ")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume:

1. a comma is wanted between elements even though the question refers to a colon
2. `df_layer` and `i` are used in the question but not defined.  We assume that the output shown is what is wanted, that `df` has one row as in the question and that `i` and `df_layer` can be disregarded.

**1)** Use `sprintf`, `shQuote` and `toString`.  `shQuote(df, "cmd")` can be optionally shortened to just `shQuote(df)` on Windows.

```
s <- sprintf('INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES (%s);', 
  toString(shQuote(df, "cmd")))
cat(s, "\n")
## INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES ("a1", "b1", "c1");
```

**2)** or possibly this variation to also insert the column names

```
s2 <- sprintf('INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES (%s);', 
  toString(names(df)), toString(shQuote(df, "cmd")))
cat(s2, "\n")
## INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES ("a1", "b1", "c1");
```

### Note

Input is

```
df <- data.frame(a = "a1", b = "b1", c = "c1")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, I want to insert a comma between the elements, and df_layer = df (I simplified my code but forgot this element)

Answer (score 0):

```r
 paste0(
      'INSERT INTO TABLE (a, b, c) VALUES ("', 
      paste(df$a, df$b, df$c, sep = '", "'), 
      '")'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just join all values like this:

```
paste(df[1,], collapse = '", "')
```

in your example it would look like this:

```
a <- c("a1")
b <- c("b1")
c <- c("c1")
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)

query = "INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES ("
query <- paste0(query, paste(df[1,], collapse = '", "'), ");")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectfly fine !

Answer (score 0):

I think just using the paste fonction can work well in your case i used the collapse parameters to specify the delimiters and just added with another parse the end of the string i just changed the string delimiters to enable the use of " inside of the string.

```
b <- c("b1")
c <- c("c1")
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
i <- 1
query = 'INSERT INTO table (a, b, c) VALUES ("'


df
paste0(query,paste(df[i,], collapse = '", "'),'");')
```

if you want you could do the same for the column names

```
b <- c("b1")
c <- c("c1")
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
i <- 1
query = 'INSERT INTO table ('
query2 = ') VALUES ("'

colnames(df)
paste0(query,paste(colnames(df),collapse=", "),query2,paste(df[i,], collapse = '", "'),'");')
```

Comment: Thank you, it's completely automatic like that

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `glue` package, though I highly, highly recommend using the `glue_data_safe()` function for anything outward facing that takes user input.

```
df = data.frame(a = "a1", b = "b1", c = "c1")
table = "(a, b, c)"
glue::glue("insert into {table} values ({paste(df[1,], collapse = ',')})")

> "insert into (abc) values (a1,b1,c1)"
```